# Most efficient way to use Ebean SqlQuery

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two Models (simplified for discussion), Parent and Child in a OneToMany relationship.  Child has a String property type.  I'd like to create a method

```
public List<String> Parent.getTypes()
```

that returns the distinct list of Types.  This is the best I could come up with:

```
public List<String> getTypes() {
    String sql = "select distinct type from child where parent_id=:id";

    SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
    sqlQuery.setParameter("parent", id);

    List<SqlRow> rows = sqlQuery.findList();
    List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>(rows.size());
    for (SqlRow row : rows)
        directions.add(row.getString("type"));

    return types;
}
```

I expect this method to be called very often.  I'm assuming this is not very efficient.  For one I am creating a new SqlQuery every time getTypes() is called even though the query is the same except the parameter.

Where is the best place to initialize a reusable SqlQuery? I tried to do it in the top of my Parent model but I get exceptions because I guess the DB is not ready when Model is initialized.  I guess I could just make it null up there and initialize it the first time getTypes() is called.  What is the "right" way to do this?

Comment: I should add that the types change almost never.  Should I also be caching this list somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Caching is quite cheap and useful, you can cache  that ie for 10 minutes:

```
public List<String> getTypes(Integer parentId) {

    List<String> types = (List<String>) Cache.get("listOfTypes");
    if (types == null) {
        List<SqlRow> rows = Ebean
             .createSqlQuery("select distinct type from child where parent_id=:id")
             .setParameter("id", parentId)
             .findList();

        types = new ArrayList<String>(rows.size());
        for (SqlRow row : rows)
            types.add(row.getString("type"));

        Cache.set("listOfTypes", types, 600);
    }

    return types;
}
```